# Scene Builder, Library is empty

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I have a problem with Scene Builder.
I probably did something wrong because in the left side menu, the library which contains the java element is empty and I didn't find how to fill it back.
[image]
Now I have to use the menu insert to get the items and it's annoying.
Does anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks

I tried searching on the net but I didn't find anyone with the same problem. I tried to add a library but nothing happened. Then I uninstalled Scene Builder and installed it again but the problem is still here, it is saved somewhere.
I'm looking to add the basic library JAVAFX or erasing everything from Scene Builder from my computer so that when I install the program, it will be back with the library.

Comment: That's weird, what version of SceneBuilder is it?  What OS version are you using?

Comment: JavaFX Scene Builder 18.0.0 and Windows 10

Comment: Check that "Show Library" is selected under the "View" menu. There may be other relevant settings under that menu too.

Comment: Already checked the "View" menu. I see the library, it's just empty

Comment: Internally, SceneBuilder seems to use the [`java.util.Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/core/preferences-api1.html#GUID-2DAC3DD0-993A-41A8-8CDC-F8E3A72E1AE3) API to store [preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).  Where it stores it is system dependent (check the linked documentation).

Comment: On Windows I think the preferences are stored in the registry.  I don't know if it is your issue, but you might need to delete the registry keys (I would think the uninstall would have done that, but perhaps not).  I don't know what the keys are.  Maybe you could determine them by looking at the attached documentation.  Maybe contact gluon for support.  Kind of annoying, I am sure...

Comment: Try the gear icon next to the library search box.  Choose "JAR/FXML Manager".  Ensure that there are no installed libraries listed (delete any which may be there).  (I'm just guessing here, you may have no custom libraries, so can ignore this comment).  Similarly for any custom libraries shown under the gear menu (I have no custom libraries so for me the "Custom Library Folder" menu item is grayed out).

Comment: The "No results found" message is what I get when I type into the search box some combination of characters that match no installed components, but it only shows no results when no matches.  If the search box is empty, as see all components in the library as expected.

Comment: There is a bunch of diagnostic info in the "Help | About Scene Builder" menu (that's on a Mac, it might be some other menu location on windows).  Copy the diagnostic info from there and paste it into your question.  Note it wasn't much use for me in understanding my setup because it listed library paths that didn't exist and log paths that were empty, so, it might not be so helpful, but maybe there will be something there to help you.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to the lastest version of SceneBuilder. https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it solved when I used the search bar, and it reload all the components on the Library menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but ONLY when the file is named Main.fxml

I decided to just deal with it by using Insert -> then whatever I needed, so I wouldn't need the left sidebar at all. But when I disabled the left sidebar and reenabled it, then everything came back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I've solved this issue by following instructions.

**file -> preferences -> Reset to Builtin Default Values**